Using a LT3482EUD to drive an avalanche photodiode
Non-engineer here... I am trying to measure low levels of light at high frequency using a DC975A (LT3482EUD demo board) and a AD500-8 TO52S1 avalanche photodiode. The board is generating 80V but I am unable to measure any voltage from the MON-OUT pin.

Do I need to add a resistor to MON-OUT? If so, what resistance, and between MON and earth or between MON and measuring device?

Am I correct in assuming that measuring at the MON-OUT pin will give me a signal proportional to the intensity of the light hitting the APD?

How could I simply test my APD to make sure it is working?


